# Rendering a file and disappeared

Tags: filesystems, recovery

I was rendering a video to a folder and I changed the name of the folder to where it was being rendered and when the video finished rendering I wasn't able to find the file no where in my pc because the folder where it had to be is not longer exists.

Any way to know where the video finished?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What is the OS? What is the filesystem? What program did you use? Was there any error message? Or a log? What did it say? Please do not respond in comments, [edit] the question and add information there.

Comment: To the null device? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device

Comment: You renamed the folder while the software was actively writing to a file inside that directory? Unless the application saves to some cache/temp directory you're out of luck.